# Declaring shared variable between classes in java

Tags: java, android-studio

I am developing an android app in android studio. I have a main activity class where I declare all my textviews, buttons, etc in a public method. In another class I use these variables to set the text views invisible, new string, etc.

When calling these variables I am currently writing:

```
  main.variable.setVisibility(true)
```

Is there a better way to go about this? Or am I doing the best practice already?

Answer (score 0):

[`setVisibility()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)) expects one of the following constant values:

> Constant  Value Description
>   `VISIBLE`      0     Visible on screen; the default value.
>   `INVISIBLE`  1     Not displayed, but taken into account during layout (space is left for it).
>   `GONE`           2     Completely hidden, as if the view had not been added.